# swift_Exec - how to know build configuration

Tags: swift, xcode, shell

I have a shell script that acts as swift proxy compiler that I embedded it in Xcode using SWIFT_EXEC build setting.

In this setting, I want to know the current build configuration, like debug, release, somethingCustom.

I tried `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` but this always show output for `release` configuration and not the current build configuration. Any idea how to get the current build configuration?

(Also, please suggest valid tags for this question)